# SQL Server query to filter column containing a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table with a column with multiple emails, e.g. `Emails` with values separated by a comma like:

```
email1@email1.com,email2@email2.com,email3@email3.com
```

From another table with `EmailAddress` column, I need to filter records containing the `Emails` e.g.

```
select EmailAddress 
from [dbo].[SomeTable1] 
where EmailAddress contains (select Emails from [dbo].[SomeTable2])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select *
 From  [dbo].[SomeTable1] A
 Join  [dbo].[SomeTable2] B
  on   charindex(','+EmailAddress ,','+Emails )>0
```

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I think EmailAddress will be the bigger string with all emails and comma seperated and will it match the emailids which comes in between, i.e with `,` in both the sides?

Comment: @JibinBalachandran  Think about it, the comma on both sides is not necessary, but it does no harm

Comment: @JohnCappelletti `EmailAddress contains 
(select Emails from [dbo].[SomeTable2])`, which one do you think is the comma seperated email  address?? I think `EmailAddress` will be bigger string and we should search for emails inside that. I'm not sure. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran In my little head Emails would be the larger string because it is plural.  EmailAddress is singular.  Granted sample data would have made things clearer

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
 SELECT DISTINCT EmailAddress 
 FROM [dbo].[SomeTable1] A
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[SomeTable2] B ON CHARINDEX(',' + Emails, + ',',',' + EmailAddress + ',')>0
```

Use `CHARINDEX` to check if the `Emails` exists in `EmailAddress` or not and `JOIN` the tables only when it exists.

Comment: @Srinath It will satisfy in both the cases.. I mean for both the emailids the where clause wll be true.

Answer (score 0):

```
select EmailAddress 
from [dbo].[SomeTable1] tab1 
where exists 
    (select 1 
    from [dbo].[SomeTable2] tab2 
    where '%,'+tab1.EmailAddress+',%' LIKE ','+tab2.Emails+',');
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a user defined function as below to split the comma separated values

```
    create FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (
          @InputString                  VARCHAR(8000),
          @Delimiter                    VARCHAR(50)
    )

    RETURNS @Items TABLE (
          Item                          VARCHAR(8000)
    )

    AS
    BEGIN
          IF @Delimiter = ' '
          BEGIN
                SET @Delimiter = ','
                SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
          END

          IF (@Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '')
                SET @Delimiter = ','

          DECLARE @Item           VARCHAR(8000)
          DECLARE @ItemList       VARCHAR(8000)
          DECLARE @DelimIndex     INT

          SET @ItemList = @InputString
          SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
          WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
          BEGIN
                SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
                INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)

                -- Set @ItemList = @ItemList minus one less item
                SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1, LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex)
                SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
          END -- End WHILE

          IF @Item IS NOT NULL -- At least one delimiter was encountered in @InputString
          BEGIN
                SET @Item = @ItemList
                INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)
          END

          -- No delimiters were encountered in @InputString, so just return @InputString
          ELSE INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString)

          RETURN

    END -- End Function
```

Final Query

```
 select EmailAddress from [dbo].[SomeTable1] where EmailAddress in
    (select item from [dbo].[SomeTable2] cross apply dbo.Split(Emails,','))
```